# How to assign the return value of a method in a condition

Tags: ruby

I have a method `match_jira_ticket` that accepts a string and returns a string or `nil`. How can I assign the return value of this method to a variable in an `if` condition?  For example, something like:

```
message = "My jira ticket is XY-1234" 
if match_jira_ticket(message)
  # assign a variable to the return value
else
  p "Unable to match"
end
```

Does this particular type of operation have a name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the assignment expression in Ruby is the value being assigned. You can therefore do the following:

```
if ticket = match_jira_ticket(message)
  p "Ticket: #{ticket}"
else
  p "Unable to match"
end
```

Comment: And the value of the `if` expression is the value of the branch that was taken, so you can further pull out the `p` like so: `p if ticket = match_jira_ticket(message) then "Ticket: #{ticket}" else 'Unable to match' end`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ticket_id = match_jira_ticket(message)).nil?
  p "Unable to match"
else
  p "Ticket is #{ticket_id}"
end
```

No idea if there is a name for this convention.